# Why is log4j logging absolutely everything when in DEBUG?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

So I'm having an issue where log4j seems to want to log absolutely everything that can "debug" when I switch the root logger to DEBUG.

This is my file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, READER
log4j.appender.READER=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.READER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.READER.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %t->%c{1} - %m%n

com.myclass.readers=DEBUG, READER
```

Now what I'd like is **only** my debug statements defined under the reader class to be printed. The issue I'm having is, it looks like the Apache HTTP package I'm using within my reader class starts dumping its debug content too.

How can I restrict this to only the stuff from my class? I've looked around online, and I'm not sure whether I'm just missing something completely, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you've set rootLogger to DEBUG level:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG
```

All loggers will inherit the level of rootLogger if not specified individually.

So set the level of rootLogger to ERROR or WARN, and then only `com.myclass.readers` is under DEBUG level.

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, READER
```

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. It was that I forgot preface my class name with log4j.logger. That works, however, it always prints everything twice, even when I set the root logger to a much higher level. Any idea why that is? These are the changes.

    log4j.rootLogger=FATAL, READER
    log4j.logger.com.myclass.readers=DEBUG, READER

Comment: Ah never mind, just realized I appended the logger twice. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The root logger should be set to ERROR, set DEBUG only to the logger of the class you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

By default root logger prints all the logs of child logger up to his logging level. If you don't want to print the logging of child loggers than set the additivity property false of that logger. 
 example - 
`<logger name="foo" additivity="false"> 
    <appender_ref ref="A2" />
</logger>`